# make Error 127 (Windows11 - ffmpeg - AudioToolboxWrapper)

Tags: cmake, makefile, mingw-w64, windows-11

---

**UPDATE: 01/25/2024** - My question has changed.  I solved the `cmake` issue by editing CMakeLists.txt and setting explicit filepaths for the compilers.  Now I have an issue with `make`.

---

**Here is the input and output of the issue:**

```
make install
```

```
[ 25%] Building C object CMakeFiles/AudioToolboxWrapper.dir/src/AudioToolboxLoader.c.obj
[ 50%] Linking C static library libAudioToolboxWrapper.a
make[1]: /bin/sh: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:86: CMakeFiles/AudioToolboxWrapper.dir/all] Error 127
make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
```

I was seeing a similar `No such file or directory` error with `cmake` earlier - I was able to solve that by looking at the output file "CMakeConfigureLog.yaml" and the configuration file "CMakeLists.txt".

---

### QUESTIONS

**QUESTION 1:** I point that out because I cannot find similar files for `make`. I do not see a log file anywhere that provides additional information, nor do I see any configuration file that I can use to tweak settings before re-attempting the command.  Is there any such log or config file for `make`?

**QUESTION 2:** Any ideas on how to approach `make` Error 127?

---

---

### LINK TO MAKEFILE2:

Line 86 is throwing the error:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_Sntb9OyYVmm7A_gC3vO7k0RdbtW8mt4JZw76TnYLlI/edit?usp=sharing

---

### **MORE DETAIL / BACKGROUND:**

I occasionally encode some audio, and I am trying to modify my install of ffmpeg using the code and instructions from the following Github repo:
https://github.com/dantmnf/AudioToolboxWrapper

**Instructions from the above Github page:**

```
# in MSYS2 MinGW shell
cd path/to/this/repo
mkdir build
cd build
prefix="$PWD/install-prefix"
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="$prefix" ..
make install

# test if we can use the wrapper library, it should not crash
./testapp

mkdir ffmpeg
cd ffmpeg
export CFLAGS="-I${prefix}/include" LDFLAGS="-L${prefix}/lib"
path/to/ffmpeg/source/tree/configure  --enable-audiotoolbox
make LD="${prefix}/bin/atw_ldwrapper"

# test if ffmpeg can use it
./ffmpeg -f lavfi -i sine=1000 -c aac_at -f mp4 -y NUL
```

My OS is Windows 11 Pro 64-bit, Version 10.0.22621  Build 22621

The example on that git mentions using MSYS2 MinGW, which I didn't have, so I did the following:

1. Created a folder at C:/01Code/ATW for this project.
2. Installed MSYS2 MINGW64 using installer from https://github.com/msys2/msys2-installer/releases
3. Began to run through the commands from AudioToolboxWrapper
4. Ran into issues running the command `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="$prefix" ..` (solved)
   4a. Ran into issues running the command `make install`
5. As part of troubleshooting, I input the following:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake
pacman -S gcc
pacman -S gdb
pacman -S cmake
pacman -S make
```

- I updated the PATH environment variable to include the msys path (C:\msys64\usr\bin)
- I opened CMD as admin and executed `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin>mklink make mingw32-make.exe` to create a symbolic link for make (recommended by another forum post).

Comment: Does the executable C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/make exist?

Comment: Just confirmed, yes make.exe exists in that directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it to run.  I'm not sure which of these things did the trick, but here is what I did:

1. Uninstalled MSYS2 entirely, rebooted.
2. Reinstalled MSYS2, rebooted.
3. Opened MINGW64, ran the following commands:
   `pacman -Suy`
   `pacman -Suy`  (again x2)
   `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc`
   `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake`
   `pacman -S make`
   `pacman -Suy`
4. Closed MINGW64, updated system environmental variable PATH to include the following directories:
   C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\   (this was already there, just being thorough)
   C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\
   C:\msys64\mingw64\
5. Opened MING64, ran the scripts again, everything went through this time.